# Ruby on Rails : Need to add data from User's form(Student data) to another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is a User's form which accepts Student's details like
Name, DOB , Email Address and Password.

The above information is stored in table called "Students"

The data "Email Address and Password" should also be saved in another table called "Users"

For Log-in to the application, authentication is checked from the "Users" table. I.e., Email Address and password to Log In.

So, on submit of the Student's form, 
1. All entered data should be stored in table called "Students". This is working.
**2. Need to store "Email Address and Password" in "Users" table. Need help/code/syntax of this.**

Answer (score 2):

You should using nested forms, see an example [there](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes)

Comment: This is basically what you want, although I would caution you to be aware of the exploitation pathways it opens you up to.